# Delete Record, reset relations before calling the deleteRecord of the adapter in Ember Data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have an issue with the deleteRecord Hook because of a tricky API I have to deal with.  Let say I have a parent/child models and i want to delete a child record. The url i have to call is something like this:

http://myapi.com/parent/:parent_id/child/:child_id

So in the deleteRecord adapter i try to build the url using the record to delete, something like:

```
deleteRecord: function(store, type, record) {
   var url = 'http://apiurl/parent/' + record.get('parent.id') + '/child/' + record.get('id') 
   ....
}
```

but the problem is when the deleteRecord of the adapter is called, the record in parameter has no relations (I think they were reseted before).

Is there a way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm running into a related problem with the latest ember / ember-data